# Inner product on V

Tags: linear-algebra

In book say that , let W be an inner product space and let T:V --> W be an isomorphism Then an inner product on V can be defined as 
          (u ,v) = (Tu ,Tv) , u,v ∈V.
My question,
Is there required T is an isomorphism for Inner product on V. I found that there is also inner product on V when T is an Linear transformation. Then why they wrote T is isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll certainly need $T$ to be injective, but being surjective is optional. The reason you need $T$ to be injective is because of the definiteness part of the positive-definite axiom. If we define
$$(v, w)_V = (Tv, Tw)_W,$$
where $( \cdot, \cdot)_W$ is the inner product of $W$, then certainly,
$$(v, v)_V = (Tv, Tv)_W \ge 0,$$
by the positivity of $( \cdot, \cdot)_W$. We also have,
$$(v, v)_V = 0 \implies (Tv, Tv)_W = 0 \implies Tv = 0,$$
but we really need $v = 0$ in order to satisfy definiteness. To get that final step from $Tv = 0$ to $v = 0$, we need injectivity.

Comment: But in positive definiteness only required that (v,v) is strictly greater than zero for non-zero v in V. Is i am right or wrong.?

Comment: You're right. But this is the contrapositive of $(v, v)_V \implies v = 0$, which is equivalent. If $T$ is not injective, then there will be **non-zero** $v$ such that $Tv = 0$. For such **non-zero** vectors, $$(v, v)_V = (Tv, Tv)_W = (0, 0)_W = 0.$$